# Advice on how to improve this stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have 2 tables:

**ReportItem**

```
id (int, primary key clustered index)
report_item  (nvarchar(100))
flow_name (nvarchar(50))
source (nvarchar(50))
```

**Tech_Details**

```
id (int, primary key clustered index)
flow_name (nvarchar(50))
source (nvarchar(50))
lang (nvarchar(5))
start_time (datetime)
```

Based on these 2 tables, I would like to produce output as below:

```
Date (start_time)  report_item    EN (lang)    BM (lang)
2015-01-01         test           3             0
2015-01-01         test           1             2
2015-01-02         test2          6             2
2015-01-02         test2          0             7
```

I have 2 stored procedures which are able to get the desired results but they are not good enough.

The **first** stored procedure is too lengthy and hard to maintain. Performance-wise, it is acceptable. Stored Procedure as below:

```
SELECT tb.date , (tb.source + '-' +tb.report_item) as report_item, sum(isnull(tb1.EN,0)) as EN, sum(isnull(tb1.BM,0)) as BM
FROM (
    SELECT (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) as date, a.report_item, a.flow_name, a.source 
    FROM ReportItem a, TechDetails b
    WHERE (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) >= @StartDate 
    AND (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) <= @EndDate
    AND a.report_id =8 AND a.flow_name = @flow_name
    GROUP BY (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))), a.report_item, a.flow_name, a.source 
) as tb 

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) as date, b.flow_name , b.source, count(*) as EN, 'Test' as report_item
    FROM TechDetails b
    WHERE(dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) >=  @StartDate AND (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) <= @EndDate
    and flow_name = @flow_name and b.lang ='EN' and b.sel_test  =1
    GROUP BY dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time)), b.flow_name, b.source, b.lang

    UNION

    SELECT (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) as date, b.flow_name , b.source, 0 as BM, count(*) as BM, 'Test' as report_item
    FROM TechDetails b
    WHERE(dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) >=  @StartDate AND (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) <= @EndDate
    and flow_name = @flow_name and b.lang ='EN' and b.sel_test  =1
    GROUP BY dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time)), b.flow_name, b.source, b.lang      

    UNION

    SELECT (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) as date, b.flow_name , b.source, count(*) as EN, 0 as BM, 'Test2' as report_item
    FROM TechDetails b
    WHERE(dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) >=  @StartDate AND (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) <= @EndDate
    and flow_name = @flow_name and b.lang ='EN' and b.sel_test2  =1
    GROUP BY dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time)), b.flow_name, b.source, b.lang              

    UNION

    SELECT (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) as date, b.flow_name , b.source, 0 as EN, COUNT(*) as BM,  'Test2' as report_item
    FROM TechDetails b
    WHERE(dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) >=  @StartDate AND (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) <= @EndDate
    and flow_name = @flow_name and b.lang ='BM' and b.sel_test2 =1
    GROUP BY dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time)), b.flow_name, b.source, b.lang


) as tb1 ON tb.flow_name = tb1.flow_name and tb.source = tb1.source and tb.report_item =tb1.report_item 
  and tb.date = tb1.date

GROUP BY tb.date , tb.flow_name, tb.report_item, tb.source
ORDER BY tb.date
```

The **Second** stored procedure is shorter and easier to maintain but it is terrible at handling large chunk of data. Stored Procedure as below:

```
SELECT (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) as date, (a.source + '-' + a.report_item) as report_item
, SUM(CASE WHEN (b.lang = 'EN' AND b.sel_test = 1 AND a.report_item = 'Test')
    OR (b.lang = 'EN' AND b.sel_test2 = 1 AND a.report_item = 'Test2') 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EN
, SUM(CASE WHEN (b.lang = 'BM' AND b.sel_test = 1 AND a.report_item = 'Test')
    OR (b.lang = 'BM' AND b.sel_test2 = 1 AND a.report_item = 'Test2') 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BM
FROM ReportItem a INNER JOIN TechDetails b ON a.source = b.source
WHERE (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) >= @StartDate 
AND (dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,b.start_time))) <= @EndDate
AND a.report_id =8 AND a.flow_name = @flow_name
GROUP BY dateadd (dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, b.start_time)), a.flow_name, a.report_item, a.source
ORDER BY dateadd (dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, b.start_time))
```

Is there any way to improve the stored procedure or other approach?

Click [here](http://pastebin.com/wKQg45YE) for Execution Plan in XML

I have changed `a.report_item` to int datatype, added non-clustered index and removed `a.source = b.source` from `CASE` but query speed did not improve. Select `CASE` from multiple tables is the root cause but I have no idea how to deal with it. `CASE WHEN (b.lang = 'BM' AND b.sel_test = 1 AND a.source = b.source AND a.report_item = 'Test'`

Comment: Looks like you are missing a join between `ReportItem` and `TechDetails`in your second query. You have the join in `SUM()` instead of as a join. That will give you the cartesian product number of rows to walk through. Could be a lot of rows.

Comment: Try to change the `FROM`clause to `FROM ReportItem a
  INNER JOIN TechDetails b 
    ON a.source = b.source
` Perhaps use `flow_name` in the join too if that returns what you want. `FROM ReportItem a
  INNER JOIN TechDetails b 
    ON a.source = b.source and
       a.flow_name = b.flow_name
`

Comment: This is a good illustration of how comma joins are easy to trip over. Just [stop using them and switch to the explicit join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Explicit INNER JOIN does help to halves the execution time, but comparatively still much slower than the 1st query especially at handling large data.

Comment: I noticed     a.report_item = 'Test' is the main cause of the slow execution time